# How to set UIButton title to null or an empty string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton

**TL;DR - My question really is: How to I set a UIButton's title to an empty string, or null after it has already been assigned a previous title.**

I have a UIButton that accepts a string generated based on the text from an NSString variable as it's title using the following:

```
NSString *MyStringVariable = @"HELLO";
...
[myButton setTitle:MyStringVariable forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

For the sake of this question, let's just assume I have "HELLO" set on my NSString variable. This then makes my UIButton have the title "HELLO", obviously...

I then have another button which removes this title from the UIbutton, like so:

```
[myButton setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Which *does* hide the UIButton's title (i.e. it now just looks like an empty UIButton), but upon further inspection, the title does infact still exist. If I add the following to my UIViewController:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    NSLog(@"Title: %@", myButton.titleLabel.text);
}
```

and navigate to and fro from this view, the title continues to get logged in the console, even though I've set the text to @"".

I have tried the following methods to make the title truly go away:

```
[myButton setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setTitle:NULL forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setTitle:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
myButton.titleLabel.text = @"";
```

The weird thing is, if I set the title to @" " (with a space):

```
[myButton setTitle:@" " forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

the title **does** update correctly, and the space is then logged to the console, rather than the old title.

**My question really is: How to I set a UIButton's title to an empty string, or null after it has already been assigned a previous title.**

Answer (score 7):

I too faced the same issue. I was setting the title of the button to `@""` for all the states, and at a later point when I check the `titlelabel.text` it gives me the previous title which is not `@""`. So I printed out all the possible values of a button as suggested by PengOne and found that the properties `titleForState` and `currentTitle` give the updated/correct values.

So instead of checking the `titleLabel.text`, try checking the `currentTitle` or `titleForState`.

I still haven't figured out why the `titleLabel` is not updated properly.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this has to do with how the `UIButton` updates its `titleLabel` property when `setTitle:forState:` is called.

For example, if you try to set the title of a button by directly accessing the `titleLabel.text` property, it does not work (check out the myriad questions on SO about this).

If you truly want to understand what's going on, then you should look at both the `titleLabel.text` and the current state of the button. One way to do this is to log `titleLabel.text`, `currentTitle`, and `titleForState:` in `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidAppear`, `viewWillDisappear`, and `viewDidDisappear`. The first two (`titleLabel.text`, `currentTitle`,) should coincide, and the third should be what you expect (`titleForState:`).

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bug in the SDK, create a [bugreport](https://bugreport.apple.com/).

If you really need a button without a title, you'll probably have to create one yourself. A UIView with it's layer set to have a cornerRadius (and hence be rounded), which responds to user interaction should do it. Also, check the [three20](http://three20.info/) toolkit, they may have a custom button or two in there you could use to save some time.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the same issue but in a different context.  I have been using NSLocalizableString to change the text in a button.

It appears that setting the **UIButton.title** changes its **UIButton.currentTitle** but not its **UIButton.titleLabel.text**.

Though it may not make much of a difference for your application, the fact that **titleLabel.txt** and **currentTitle** are different turns to be more of a "be aware" than an implementation challenge.